# Rocketchat integration with AWX Tower notification

Tags: rocket.chat, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I'm looking for a way how to integrate a notification for Ansible Tower / AWX to Rocket.Chat? I can't find a suitable script for Rocket.Chat integration.

Answer (score 0):

First go in Rocket.Chat in Administration > Integration and then create a new incoming webhook. Configure it as wanted (name, bot, channel, etc.) enable scripting and add the following script:

```
class Script {
  process_incoming_request({ request }) {
    // UNCOMMENT THE BELOW LINE TO DEBUG IF NEEDED.
    // console.log(request.content);

    let body = request.content.body;

    if (!body) {
      let id = request.content.id;
      let name = request.content.name;
      let url = request.content.url;
      let status = request.content.status;
      let type = request.content.friendly_name;
      let project = request.content.project;
      let playbook = request.content.playbook;
      let hosts = request.content.hosts;
      let created_by = request.content.created_by;
      let started = request.content.started;
      let finished = request.content.finished;
      let traceback = request.content.traceback;
      let inventory = request.content.inventory;
      let credential = request.content.credential;
      let limit = request.content.limit;
      let extra_vars = request.content.extra_vars;


      let message = "";
      message += "AWX "+type+" "+name+" ("+id+") ";
      message += "on project _"+project+"_ ";
      message += "running playbook _"+playbook+"_ ";
      message += "has status *"+status+"*.";
      message += "\n";

      message += type+" was created by _"+created_by+"_ for inventory _"+inventory+"_ ";
      if (limit !== "") {
        message += "with limit _"+limit+"_ ";
      }
      message += " and using the _"+credential+"_ credentials.\n";

      if (Object.keys(hosts).length != 0) {
        message += "Hosts: "+Object.keys(hosts).length+" (ok/changed/skipped/failures)\n";

        for (let [name, host] of Object.entries(hosts)) {
          message += "- "+name+" ("+host.ok+"/"+host.changed+"/"+host.skipped+"/"+host.failures+")";
          if (host.failed === false) {
            message += " is *ok*\n";
          } else {
            message += " has *failed*\n";
          }
        }
      }

      return {
        content: {
          "text": "AWX notification *"+status+"* on "+type+" "+name+" ("+id+")",
          "attachments": [
            {
              "title": type+": "+name+"",
              "title_link": url,
              "text": message,
              "color": "#764FA5"
            }
          ]
        }
      };
    } else {
      return {
        content: {
          text: "AWX notification: " + request.content.body
        }
      };
    }
  }    
}
```

Save and activate the webhook. Now you get a Webhook URL from Rocket.Chat. Copy that URL.

Go to your AWX instance and create a new Notification of type Webhook and paste the Webhook URL from Rocket.Chat. You can test the notifcation within AWX.

The script does not print extra vars, because they could contain passwords etc. But you'll see failed hosts and some more information about the job.

Answer (score 0):

AWX/Tower has the ability to send notifications to rocket.chat without any custom scripts.

In Tower go to Notifications and add a new one with type 'Rocket.Chat' then set the Target URL to be the URL of a blank incoming webhook in Rocket.Chat (Make sure it's enabled at the top).

(Note: Be careful of the URL Rocket.Chat gives you for the integration, mine didn't give me a URL with the correct port of 3000 within the URL so it failed at first)



Heres what the notifcations read as:

Bot -
3:13 PM
Tower Notification Test 1 https://ruupansi01
Bot -
3:15 PM
Project Update #2 'Test Project' succeeded: https://tower/#/jobs/project/1

Comment: Yes, you're right, that is new to me, but my script contains also more informations from the WebHook f.e per Host status. So you don't need to go into the Webinterface of AWX.